# Building deployment packages based on specific Work Item / Changesets using TFS Build 2015

Tags: deployment, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild, continuous-deployment

I'm struggling to find solid documentation around this area. Is it possible, out of the box, to trigger builds / create deployment packages based on a provided list of Work Items / Changesets? Ultimately I want only the changed files/dlls to be produced, and not the entire source.

My initial thought was to create a build definition that maps all of the team project source code, and pass in the work items / changesets ids as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

To build specific changeset in TFS, when you queue one build, please go to Parameters -> 1.TF Version Control -> Get Version. The screenshot below shows TFS build changeset 258.

[image]

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with TFS 2015 - there's a new web UI